# ember.js - ReferenceError: Todos is not defined

Tags: ember.js

I am having a big trouble training to use ember.js. When I add the following code in http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/adding-a-route-and-template/ all my contents disappeared.

Firebug detect: "ReferenceError: Todos is not defined", but was defined in todo.js e loaded properly in index.html:

**todo.js**

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean')
});

Todos.Todo.FIXTURES = [
 {
   id: 1,
   title: 'Learn Ember.js',
   isCompleted: true
 },
 {
   id: 2,
   title: '...',
   isCompleted: false
 },
 {
   id: 3,
   title: 'Profit!',
   isCompleted: false
 }
];
```

This is a link to all my files: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6416743 (not included the base js files).

I do everything in the tutorial until http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the creation of your `Application instance`. This must be the first Ember statement in your javascript. Put it after the library reference and before your own code. This **creates the namespace Todos** and afterwards afterwards you can put objects like `Todos.Todo` into that namespace.

```
var Todos = Ember.Application.create({});
```

Comment: What you said is correlated with my problem. I forgot to load application.js e router.js BEFORE todo.js. Thank you very much!

Comment: Then plz close the question, if you are happy :-)